# Python with iis import modules

Tags: python, iis

I have a working python 3.7.3 (Anaconda) and configured iis 10 on windows 10

I address the following script via http://127.0.0.1/py3/hw.py

This works without error so modules can be imported

```
import sys

print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('')
print('Hello, world! ')
```

but the following does not work using http://127.0.0.1/py3/hw.py, claiming that the module numpy can't be located
though running it from the Anaconda command prompt does work

```
import sys
import numpy

print('Content-Type: text/html')
print('')
print('Hello, world! ')
```

I presume there is a path issue here
I have tried adding the Anaconda path additions to the standard windows path which does not work

Any suggestions most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some test on my local and it is working fine.

1.I installed numpy via command line: **pip install numpy==1.17.3**

2.Please ensure your authenticated user like  **NT Authority/IUSR** have enough permission to access your python's lib folder.

It is recommended to troubleshooting this issue with Microsoft Process monitor and scan access denied error inside w3wp.exe or python.exe.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, seems it is an issue with Anaconda distribution I will continue to work on it